# C# Close WPF Form from background Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, forms

I'm looking for a way to close a form from a background thread.
The scenario:
it's a chat application with a thread in background to manage the tcp client
now i want to close the first form from this thread

App.xaml.cs

```
public List<Window> dialogs = new List<Window>();

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    Login loginDialog = new Login();
    GUI.MainWindow mainDialog = new GUI.MainWindow();

    dialogs.Add(loginDialog);
    dialogs.Add(mainDialog);

    client = new Klassen.TClient(dialogs);

    if (loginDialog.ShowDialog() != true)
        return;
}
```

the TClient class

```
public class TClient
{
    public TSocket socket;

    public TClient(List<Window> dialogs)
    {
        socket = new TSocket(dialogs);
    }
}
```

the TSocket class, with the background thread

```
public class TSocket
{
    /* Variables */
    List<Window> dialogs;

    public TSocket(List<Window> dialogs)
    {
        this.dialogs = dialogs;
        clientThread = new Thread(connectionWorker);
        clientThread.Start();
    }

    public bool connect()
    {
        /* Connect */
    }

    void connectionWorker()
    {
        connect();
        while (isConnected)
        {
            /* if statment */
            Login loginDialog = (Login)dialogs[0];
            //dialogs[1].Close();
        }
    }
}
```

i already tried to work with a delagate and invoke , but it didn't worked properly

Comment: Have you considered abstracting your TSocket class so that I doesn't work directly with UI? Like rather then directly calling Window class, it exposes events that you handle in UI (like connected / disconnected)?

Comment: how should the event's look like ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows programming allows only working with main UI thead for UI operations.

```
    static class UiUtils
    {
    static UiUtils()
    {
        Dispatcher = Application.Current == null
            ? null
            : Application.Current.Dispatcher;
    }

    public static Dispatcher Dispatcher { get; private set; }

    public static void InvokeMainThread(this Action action)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Dispatcher != null && !Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
            else
                action();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error invoking main thread: {0}", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

And in your code you should call from any thread:

```
UiUtils.InvokeMainThread(()=>{loginDialog.Close();});`
```